# Tables in control-m, are they unique

Tags: control-m

**Table names** in Control-m jobs which is mentioned under one Control-m instance, do they need to have unique names?

Answer (score 1):

Table names need to be unique under one instance CTM Server. So, usually the naming standard is set as -

This ensures that under one application, all the table names are unique.
If you try to create a new table with same name, it will not let you save the table, and will throw a message that the table with same name is already

Ex: If Table1 is a common table (name) in both application App1 and App2, then -

APP1_P_TABLE1 / APP2_P_TABLE1

This helps in classification. Additional features like 'Group Name' and 'Application' also helps the classification, which is also used while giving access to users.

Answer (score 0):

You can have several jobs with the same name but table names are unique.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Table name should be unique.